# Build a flutter application for windows platforms on Mac

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

Can I build a flutter application for windows platform on Mac?

Because I don't want to install a visual studio on my Mac just for build.

Is there any totally "command-line" way to build a windows .exe file on IOS operating system?

Plus:If I want to add the build process to CICD, It's hard to make the build on CI-machine

Answer (score 0):

The  [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile)  says:

No cross-compilation support [issue 28617](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28617)

The compiler supports creating machine code only for the operating system it’s running on. You need to run the compiler three times — on macOS, Windows, and Linux — to create executables for all three operating systems. A workaround is to use a CI (continuous integration) provider that supports all three operating systems.